# Three.js - mtlLoader materials

Tags: three.js, mtl-file

```
  mtlLoader.load('.mtl_file_path', function (materials) {
    materials.preload()

    console.log(materials.materials)

    objLoader.setMaterials(materials)

    objLoader.load('/resource/obj/mycar.obj', function (car) {
      do somthing
    })
  })
```

This is my code. I want to know my mtl's values.
So, console.log(materials.materials)

console result is 
[image]

I can see in my brower console, but i don't know how can approach it on code.

I tried

```
console.log(materials.materials[0])
console.log(materials.materials{"midnight_blue"})
console.log(materials.materials.midnight_blue)
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(materials.materials.midnight_blue)`?

Comment: just 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

```
materials.preload()
console.log(materials.materials.midnight_blue)
```

Comment: Maybe it's asynchronous, so need to load it in advance.